# Get Displayed Position of DataGridView Row

Tags: c#, datagridview

The easiest way I see to explain what I need is via example.

Suppose I have a DataGridView with 20 rows of data.  The DGV is sized to show 10 rows at a time.  It is scrolled to show rows 4-13.  Row 7 is selected.  What I need is a way to get that Row7 is the 4th displayed row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the DataGridViewRows in a DGV and check each Row's `Displayed` property.  When you find the first one's that's true, that's your first displayed row.  Continue looping and checking the Row's `Selected` property.

Here's some test code:

```
int foundRowIndex = 0;
bool foundFirstDisplayedRow = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows) {
    if (row.Displayed) {
        foundFirstDisplayedRow = true;
        Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[0].Value);
    }
    if (foundFirstDisplayedRow) {
       foundRowIndex++;
       if (row.Selected) {
          // You've got what you need here in foundRowIndex.
       }
    }
}
```

As a bonus, you can check the Displayed property of the 7th row to make sure the user didn't do anything crazy like size the DGV to stop displaying it.

Comment: That works.  I was hoping their was a more direct way though.